# @MultiPartConfig Customized Message

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, multipartconfig

In my Servlet I use the `@MultiPartConfig` annotation in combination with the `maxFileSize` attribute. This works as expected. The only issue I have is that I want to customize the Message (into Dutch). Is there a nice and clean way to achieve this?

My site is just a simple JSP.

Comment: Which message do you want to translate? There are no messages directly associated with the `@MultiPartConfig` annotation.

Comment: @DaDaDom Think thats the key of my problem. When I use a File that exceeds the maxFileSize. The jsp is showing: " SRVE8021E: The file being uploaded is too large.".

What I'm looking for is a nice and clean way to customize this message.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize message in application level
e.g. you can catch exception and throw new exception containing some message or print html in response or forward request to some error page.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        Part filePart = req.getPart(FILE_PART_NAME);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        String msg=e.getMessage();
        if(msg!=null) {
            if(msg.contains("SRVE8021E")) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Etwas auf Deutsch sagen");
            }
        }
```